# AWS s3 trying to fix error s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am new to python and
I am trying to check if a bucket exists or needs to be created, but I am getting this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2vBS.png)

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    

    def check_bucket(bucket):
        try:
            s3.meta.client.head_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name) #Error line <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            print("Bucket Exists!")
            return True
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            # If a client error is thrown, then check that it was a 404 error.
            # If it was a 404 error, then the bucket does not exist.
            error_code = int(e.response['Error']['Code'])
            if error_code == 403:
                print("Private Bucket. Forbidden Access!")
                return True
            elif error_code == 404:
                print("Bucket Does Not Exist!")
                return False


    if_bucket_accessable = check_bucket(bucket_name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error states that the credentials are not found. So you have to specify the credentials while creating s3 object as below:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,aws_secret_access_key= SECRET_KEY)
```

Adding access and secret key in code is not safe. So you can configure the same using the was cli command once:

```
aws configure
```

Fill in the details that are prompted on execution of above command

Answer (score 0):

this link might be helpful if you are using windows

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3KacV0UlSM
```

This video will give you a complete step by step walktrough. Let me know if you get stuck somewhere